# What is the need of EIPAssociation resource if we can directly associate EIP to an instance using Instance Property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I was wondering the probable usage of EIPAssociation resource in Cloud Formation, though we can directly associate EIP with an EC2 instance using instance property of EIP & directly providing the instance reference.

Are there any specific issue in direct referencing instance via property & what would be the best practice to address this issue in cloud formation.

Comment: I am not aware of any property called EIP for AWS::EC2::Instance. If you are thinking of associating the elastic IP with public IP, that may not work since "You can associate a public IP address with a network interface only if it has a device index of 0 and if it is a new network interface (not an existing one).".

Comment: OP is right, you can associate an EIP directly to an instance - bypassing the need for a EPIAssociation. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip.html

Comment: One example of usage is right here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html#w2ab1c21c10d113c36c15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, [AWS::EC2::EIPAssociation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-eip-association.html) allows you to achieve more than just EIP - Instance association that you would find in AWS::EC2::EIP.

One of the more notable case is that when you want to attach EIP to a specific network interface on a instance with multiple network interface

Comment: Whether, I directly associate or associate via network interface, how does it going to makes a difference.

A single IP is going to be associated to a single machine.

From actual logical scenario this looks good, but if i directly associate how are we going to know which interface is used by EIP ?

Comment: It is good to have that flexibility. Ex: you create an EC2 from AMI with pre-install application. The first app always go through network interface 1, the second app to the second network interface. Each application will have their own "route" and out-going IP. 
For the second point, I do not know which NIC will get the EIP attached to in that case

Comment: Yupp, the same thing I was also curious about.